# Closure's (apply str) questions?

Tags: clojure

With closure

```
(apply str [\a \b])
```

and

```
(apply str '(\a \b))
```

returns "ab".

```
(apply str (\a \b))
```

returns an error.

Why is that?

Comment: I don't know Clojure, but is it possible [] is a list but () is something else?

Comment: @jtbandes: [] is a vector (think like a array that grows). () is a list but it gets evaluated as a function if its not quoted. Thats the Code is Data Thing around Lisps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `(\a \b)` means "call the function `\a` with an argument of `\b`", and since the character `\a` is not a function, it fails. Note the difference in the following:

```
user=> (+ 1 2 3)
6
user=> '(+ 1 2 3)
(+ 1 2 3)
```

As a general rule, if you want to write a literal sequence, use a vector instead of a quoted list since the quote will also stop evaluation of the parts inside the list, e.g.:

```
user=> [(+ 1 2) (+ 3 4)]
[3 7]
user=> '((+ 1 2) (+ 3 4))
((+ 1 2) (+ 3 4))
```